# Function returning reversed string in C - allocate

Tags: c, reverse

I need to allocate `t2` but I don't know exactly how.

```
char *reverse(char *t)
{
    int length= strlen(t);
    char *t2 = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i= (length-1);i>=0;i--)
       t2[i]=t[length-1];
    return t2;
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: You need to allocate one more byte for the special `'\0'` char which indicates the end of string.

Comment: @Maroun, OP's problem is almost certainly that he's allocating *too much* memory in this case - note the multiplication by pointer size.

Comment: @CarlNorum Oh.. I missed that.. sure, after this fix, he needs to allocate one more byte :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors with the code.

As mentioned before `sizeof(char) != sizeof(char*)` the former is the size of a char the second the size of a pointer.

Also the loop only assigns the same value to all indices in t2
`t2[i]=t[length-1];`

Furthermore it should take a `const char*` as argument so even const char* strings can be passed to it.

No null character `\0` is set at the end of the string.

This code should do it:

```
char* reverse(const char *t)
{
    int length= strlen(t);
    char* t2 = (char*)malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
      t2[(length-1)-i]=t[i];
    }
    t2[length] = '\0';
    return t2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close.

```
char *t2 = malloc(length + 1); // reserve space for a null terminator
```

You probably want that loop to start at `length`, and not `length - 1`, though.  The assignment inside the loop is wrong, too (you only change the destination location, not the source).  Make sure to null terminate the string before returning it.

Editorial Notes:

1. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.
2. `sizeof(char)` is `1` - no need to multiply.
3. Depending on the semantics you're looking for, you might not need to `malloc()` at all.  String reversal can be done in-place in C.

Comment: @AdrianJandl Really? Pointers are 4 bytes on 64-bit systems? What about in embedded 8-bit or 16-bit systems? Your comment is wrong - the `sizeof` of a pointer is platform-specific.

Comment: @NikBougalis You're right actually, I keep forgetting this, as I only work on a machine where pointers are 4 Bytes long, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *t2 = malloc(length*sizeof(char) + 1);
```

you malloc a pointer to type char plus one for zero termination

Comment: Why not simply `length + 1`?

Comment: you are right, but that is the only case with char. all other types are multiplied by their size, so why not here for symmetric reasons

Comment: @VladLazarenko It is also more clear so the OP can better understand the allocation.

Comment: @PeterMiehle It's considered bad practice to multiply by `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @Peter, if you want to be "safe", you could multiply by `sizeof *t2`, I guess.  Then at least you'd get some potential future refactoring help.  But for a function like this one?  Why bother....

Comment: you all right. -closed- Carl Norum's answer is more elaborate

Comment: Peter Miehle's solution gives me error: `IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"`